# How does the Get-ChildItem -Exclude Parameter work?

Tags: powershell

How does the Get-ChildItem -Exclude parameter work?  What rules does it follow?

The Get-Help for Get-ChildItem isn't detailed at all:

> Omits the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies the
>   Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt".
>   Wildcards are permitted.

And on Stackoverflow and elsewhere the general consensus seems to be it's too difficult to use and we should all just pipe the output of Get-ChildItem to Where-Object instead.

While I'm willing to use Where-Object I'm curious as to the rules -Exclude follows.

For example, I have a folder with the following sub-folders:

```
HsacFixtures
HsacFixturesBuild
RestFixture
RestFixtureBuild
```

If I execute the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem $rootFolderPath -Exclude HsacFixturesBuild -Directory
```

it returns the results expected:

```
HsacFixtures
RestFixture
RestFixtureBuild
```

However, if I add a -Recurse parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem $rootFolderPath -Exclude HsacFixturesBuild -Directory -Recurse
```

Then it returns sub-folders in the HsacFixturesBuild folder.

I've also tried `HsacFixturesBuild\` and `HsacFixturesBuild\*`, which have the same results.

So does -Exclude only apply to immediate children, and not to grand-children or deeper sub-folders?

Comment: get-help Get-ChildItem -full, has examples and details.

Comment: @KoryGill: Thanks but I'd already checked help -full.  There's only one example with -Exclude and the parameter description is very brief (see the quote in my question).  It wasn't enough to understand the rules it operates under.

Comment: @SimonTewsi, Exclude filters on the name of the object. So even though the object is a grandchild the exclude only looks at the object name, not the path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Exclude` omits child objects based on the [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx),

> For files, gets the name of the file. For directories, gets the name
>   of the last directory in the hierarchy if a hierarchy exists.
>   Otherwise, the Name property gets the name of the directory

not the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx),

> which gets the full path of the directory or file

So even though the object is a grandchild in a recursive call, the exclude only looks at the object's `Name`, not the `FullName` so the exclude wont affect omission unless the child objects share a common substring of the name that happens to be part of the exclude parameter

**Source [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800(v=wps.640).aspx)**

> **Example 3: Get all child items using an inclusion and exclusion**
>
> This command lists the .txt files in the Logs subdirectory, ***except for
>   those whose names start with the letter A***. It uses the wildcard
>   character (*) to indicate the contents of the Logs subdirectory, not
>   the directory container. Because the command does not include the
>   Recurse parameter, the command does not include the content of
>   directory automatically; you need to specify it.
>
> Windows PowerShell
>
> ```
> PS C:\> Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\Windows\Logs\*" -Include "*.txt" -Exclude "A*"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

With respect to `Get-ChildItem`,`-exclude` parameter works on the objects `name`

It could be understood better from the following example:
Consider the following folder structure

[image]

First we use -exclude parameter without recurse.
[image]

As we could see in the above image, based on objects `name` , `folder` was excluded

Now we add recurse parameter to the above statement as follows
[image]

Now we see  could see that sub-folders of `folder` is still present, because the exclusion was applied at objects `name`

Hope this HElps.