# Exclude file from powershell Get-ChildItem results

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

To select every AssemblyInfo.cs from a directory minus specifically one, I run a powershell script :

```
Clear-Host
$SrcDir = "D:\Projects\Lambda\Sources"
Write-Host $SrcDir
cd $SrcDir
$ExcludeXYZCallStrategy = $SrcDir + "\Lambda.XYZ\XYZCallStrategy\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
# 2. Select Files to be updated
Write-Host $ExcludeXYZCallStrategy
# both these syntaxes fail (tried one after the other not together ofc) :
$Assemblyfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcDir -Recurse -Include AssemblyInfo.cs -Exclude $ExcludeXYZCallStrategy
$Assemblyfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcDir -Recurse -Include AssemblyInfo.cs -Exclude D:\Projects\Lambda\Sources\Lambda.XYZ\XYZCallStrategy\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
Write-Host $Assemblyfiles
Write-Host "Files Count : " $Assemblyfiles.count
```

I tried different syntaxes to force Get-ChildItem to exclude that one file but I failed.

I tried these these answers to no avail :

- [How to use Get-ChildItem with excluding a list of items with an array in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866889/how-to-use-get-childitem-with-excluding-a-list-of-items-with-an-array-in-powersh)
- [Get-ChildItem Exclude and File parameters don't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191453/get-childitem-exclude-and-file-parameters-dont-work-together)

From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6), I found nothing that would explain why the file is not excluded.

Comment: As a workaround you could to this: `| Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $ExcludeXYZCallStrategy}`

Comment: @guiwhatsthat It works  ! thanks ! but why exclude is not working ?

Comment: It's just a guess but I think the exclude parameter only checks the name property of the object and you tried to use the fullname property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's only one file, you could use `Where-Object`.

```
$Assemblyfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SrcDir -Recurse -Include AssemblyInfo.cs | Where-Object { $_.FullName -ne "D:\Projects\Lambda\Sources\Lambda.XYZ\XYZCallStrategy\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" }
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you ! Could you explain me why the Exclude does not ?

Comment: [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370854/how-does-the-get-childitem-exclude-parameter-work) your `-exclude` parameter doesn't work!